How to perform window function with where clause?
From the columns 1-4 in the table below I'd like to create a query that can return columns 5 & 6:



my_date
cat_1_id
cat_2_id
my_value
cat_2_id_1_value
cat_2_id_2_value




01/01/2024
1
1
1
1
Null


01/01/2024
2
1
2
2
Null


02/01/2024
1
2
3
1
3


02/01/2024
2
2
4
2
4


03/01/2024
1
1
5
5
3


03/01/2024
2
1
6
6
4



The logic of the query:
This is in essence a pivoting of data contained within columns 1-4.
Column 5:

If cat_2_id = 1 then display my_value for that row
If cat_2_id != 1 then display my_value for the last row where cat_id_1 matches the current row and cat_2_id = 1

Column 6:
This is the same principle as column 5 just for cat_2_id = 2. So:

If cat_2_id = 2 then display my_value for that row
If cat_2_id != 2 then display my_value for the last row where cat_id_1 matches the current row and cat_2_id = 2

Current progress:
I've got as far as a solution that involves CASE to:

get my_value if cat_2_id condition is met, or;
get my_value for the last row using LAST_VALUE window function along with a combination of PARTITION BY (cat_1_id) and ORDER BY (my_date) and RANGE BETWEEN.

However, I can't get my head around how to build in the additional filter within the window function to ensure the cat_2_id condition is met for the last row.
I found this post that uses FILTER for postgresql but I couldn't find this in the MySQL docs (plus it says it isn't implemented for non-aggregate window functions).
If there isn't a window function way of doing this then I'd be happy with anything that does the job!
Here's the data to recreate:
CREATE TABLE test.pivot_cols (
    pivot_by_cols_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    my_date DATE NOT NULL, 
    cat_1_id INT NOT NULL, 
    cat_2_id INT NOT NULL, 
    my_value INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `test`.`pivot_cols` (`my_date`, `cat_1_id`, `cat_2_id`, `my_value`) VALUES ('2000-01-01', '1', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `test`.`pivot_cols` (`my_date`, `cat_1_id`, `cat_2_id`, `my_value`) VALUES ('2000-01-01', '2', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `test`.`pivot_cols` (`my_date`, `cat_1_id`, `cat_2_id`, `my_value`) VALUES ('2000-01-02', '1', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO `test`.`pivot_cols` (`my_date`, `cat_1_id`, `cat_2_id`, `my_value`) VALUES ('2000-01-02', '2', '2', '4');
INSERT INTO `test`.`pivot_cols` (`my_date`, `cat_1_id`, `cat_2_id`, `my_value`) VALUES ('2000-01-02', '1', '1', '5');
INSERT INTO `test`.`pivot_cols` (`my_date`, `cat_1_id`, `cat_2_id`, `my_value`) VALUES ('2000-01-02', '2', '1', '6');


How to perform window function with where clause? This is absolutely impossible. Apply window fn in CTE then test according column in outer WHERE.

This is pretty horrible but it provides your desired output - db<>fiddle

@user1191247 - thanks :). As the table is a few million rows then it's likely that this solution will be fairly slow? I see Akina has proposed using CTEs which I assume would be faster but I'm not able to follow exactly what he is proposing...

Correlated queries only. Can't be done with window functions.

On second thought, is cat_2_id guaranteed to be 1 or 2?

Can there be multiple rows for the same (cat_1_id, cat_2_id) pair on the same my_date? Is there any possibility of pivot_by_cols_id increasing while my_date decreases between any two rows?

@user1191247 - no there can't. Sorry, missed that off the create table statement

You may begin with a correlated subquery which is easier to implement and understand:
select *, case when cat_2_id = 1 then my_value else (
  select my_value
  from pivot_cols as x
  where cat_1_id = pivot_cols.cat_1_id
  and cat_2_id = 1
  and my_date < pivot_cols.my_date
  order by my_date desc
  limit 1
) end as id_1_value, case when cat_2_id = 2 then my_value else (
  select my_value
  from pivot_cols as x
  where cat_1_id = pivot_cols.cat_1_id
  and cat_2_id = 2
  and my_date < pivot_cols.my_date
  order by my_date desc
  limit 1
) end as id_2_value
from pivot_cols
order by my_date, cat_1_id

If you must use window functions, it could have been straight forward if MySQL supported ignore nulls in window functions. Sadly it doesn't so you need to use some trick. In the following query I use max() over () to find the prior date conditionally. Additional joins are used to fetch the values:
with cte as (
  select
    *,
    max(case when cat_2_id = 1 then my_date end) over prev_rows as date_1,
    max(case when cat_2_id = 2 then my_date end) over prev_rows as date_2
  from pivot_cols
  window prev_rows as (
    partition by cat_1_id
    order by my_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
  )
)
select
  cte.*,
  case when cte.cat_2_id = 1 then cte.my_value else j1.my_value end as id_1_value,
  case when cte.cat_2_id = 2 then cte.my_value else j2.my_value end as id_2_value
from cte
left join pivot_cols as j1 on cte.cat_1_id = j1.cat_1_id and cte.date_1 = j1.my_date 
left join pivot_cols as j2 on cte.cat_1_id = j2.cat_1_id and cte.date_2 = j2.my_date
order by cte.my_date, cte.cat_1_id

Demo on DB<>Fiddle
